# using find sort and wc -l in the one command

Tags: bash, sorting, find, wc

This is how find files using find and show the number of lines in each file

```
$ find ./ -type f -name "data*.csv" -exec wc -l {} +
   380723 ./data_2016-07-07-10-41-13.csv
   369869 ./data_2016-07-11-10-42-01.csv
   363941 ./data_2016-07-08-10-41-50.csv
   378981 ./data_2016-07-12-10-41-28.csv
  1493514 total
```

**how do I sort the results by file name?** Below is my attempt, but it is not working.

```
$ find ./ -type f -name "data*.csv" -exec wc -l {} + | sort
1493514 total
363941 ./data_2016-07-08-10-41-50.csv
369869 ./data_2016-07-11-10-42-01.csv
378981 ./data_2016-07-12-10-41-28.csv
380723 ./data_2016-07-07-10-41-13.csv
$ find ./ -type f -name "data*.csv" | sort -exec wc -l {} +
sort: invalid option -- 'e'
Try `sort --help' for more information.
$ find ./ -type f -name "data*.csv" -exec sort | wc -l {} +
find: wc: {}missing argument to `-exec'
: No such file or directory
wc: +: No such file or directory
0 total
$
```

**Can someone offer a solution and correct me so I understand it better?**

### EDIT1

from `man sort`

```
  -k, --key=POS1[,POS2]
          start a key at POS1 (origin 1), end it at POS2 (default end of line).  See POS syntax below


   POS is F[.C][OPTS], where F is the field number and C the character position in the field; both are origin 1.  If neither -t nor -b is in effect, characters in a field are counted from the begin‐
   ning of the preceding whitespace.  OPTS is one or more single-letter ordering options, which override global ordering options for that key.  If no key is given, use the entire line as the key.
```

Comment: You can look into the `-k` flag to `sort`

Comment: @IsmailBadawi can you clarify what the complete command is? ok someone posted in answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ismail's suggestion of using `sort -k` is correct. However, I'm often too lazy to learn (or relearn) how `-k` works, so here's a cheap solution:

```
find . -name 'data*.csv' -print0 | sort -z | xargs -0 wc -l
```

Edit: after some experimentation, I did figure out how `-k` works:

```
find . -name 'data*.csv' -exec wc -l {} + | sort -k 2
```

Comment: tks.what does the `2` do in `sort -k 2`?